# MySql slow query logs in production environment

Tags: mysql, database-performance

We're using MySql 5.5 in our production environment. Is it advisable to turn on slow query logs in production? What is the performance implication of doing so? I referred official doc [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html), but it doesn't say anything about performance.

Comment: If you found one of the answers helpful, could you please mark them as accepted to close out this question?

Answer (score 11):

I highly recommend turning ON the slow query log in production environment. No matter how much logging you have done in your dev/QA/pre-prod environment, nothing gives you a better idea of the true performance than a production environment. Performance hit, in my experience, has not been significant.

You can improve performance, if it becomes significant, by saving your slow query log on a different disk or disk array.

`long_query_time` dynamic variable helps MySQL determine what to write in the slow query log. If your `long_query_time` is 2 seconds and you see a whole bunch of queries being logged in the slow query log, you can raise the `long_query_time` using something like `SET GLOBAL long_query_time=10` or change it in my.cnf and restart MySQL.

I prefer keeping long_query_time to around 3 seconds to start and see what gets logged, and resolve the slowness in a timely manner. After that I drop it down to 2 seconds and keep it there. Logging is one thing, but taking action on the logging - may it be resolving the long running queries, monitoring the IO with `iostat -x` or `sar` etc. - is vital.

Answer (score 0):

I never found any Performance penalties on using slow-query log so I think it's save to turn it on. The database just keeps an extra logfile where it will store query exceeding a certain runtime (configurable). You can Analyse the slow queries after that e.g. by doing an

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ... FROM ...
```